# Prove that hyperbolic isometry with constant distance is the identity

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, isometry

Let $f$ be an isometry of the Poincaré half-plane model of two-dimensional hyperbolic geometry, denoted by $\mathbb{H}^2$. Prove that if the distance $d(z,f(z))=c$ for some constant $c\geq0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{H}^2$, then $f$ is the identity isometry.

This is of course not true in the Euclidean case. A translation in the Euclidean plane has constant distance but is not the identity.

My first idea was to prove the contrapositive - that if $f$ weren't the identity, then it would have to be one of the non-trivial isometries, so expressible as either:
$$f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d} \quad \text{or} \quad f(z)=\frac{a\bar{z}+b}{c\bar{z}+d}$$
For some $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $ad-bc=1$ in the former case (orientation preserving) and $ad-bc=-1$ in the latter (orientation reversing), with the added condition that $(a,b,c,d)\neq(1,0,0,1)$ in the former case, as we do not want the identity.

But this approach is quite unwieldy and requires the use of the distance function, taking cross-ratios $\textit{et cetera}$. I believe there must be a slicker solution using the concept of fixed points or some other notion of hyperbolic geometry.

All help or input would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't want me to use the distance function, what am I allowed to use?

Comment: For example, this problem would be a snap if I could use the classification of isometries.

Comment: @LeeMosher I mean that the method suggested above required the consideration of separate cases and computing the explicit distance of two points, using the explicit distance function $d(A,B)=|\textrm{log}[A,B,X,Y]|$ in each case. One is, naturally, going to have to use the notion of distance to solve the problem.
And by classification of isometries, do you mean to say that we can use the fact that if the isometry is not the identity, then it is either parabolic, elliptic, hyperbolic or loxodromic, and then show in each case that none of these types isometries fix distances?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant regarding classification of isometries. I can write an answer like that if you want.

Comment: @LeeMosher I believe I understand what your argument entails. We know that if the isometry $f$ belongs to one of the four classes of non-identity isometries, then at least one point is fixed, and so we must have $c=0$ (with $c$ defined above) - contradicting the fact that the isometry is not the identity. My only scruples with this argument are that if we let $f$ be a parabolic isometry, so that it only preserves one point, and let the preserved point be $\infty$. Can we say that $d(\infty,f(\infty))=0 \implies c=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proof, which uses the classification of isometries.

But first I need to address an issue that you raised in the comments.

**Warning:** When an isometry acts on the compactified hyperbolic plane $\overline{\mathbb H}^2 = \mathbb H^2 \cup S^1_\infty$ it always has at least one fixed point of $\overline{\mathbb H}^2$. **But,** points in $S^1_\infty$ are not involved in distance measurements; points in $S^1_\infty$ are "infinitely far" and are not part of the domain of the distance function; $d(p,q)$ is only defined for $p,q \in \mathbb H^2$.

So the problem asks to prove that if $f$ is not the identity then $d(p,f(p))$ is not constant for $p \in \mathbb H^2$.

Having said that, let me go through the cases of non-identity isometries. Let $Fix(f)$ be the fixed point set of $f$ on $\overline{\mathbb H}^2$, which breaks into two pieces: the finite fixed points $Fix_{fin}(f) = Fix(f) \cap \mathbb H^2$, and the infinite fixed points $Fix_{inf}(f) = Fix(f) \cap S^1_\infty$.

Every non-identity isometry falls into one of four cases, as follows:

Case 1: $Fix(f)$ consists of two infinite points $\xi,\eta \in {Fix}_{inf}(f)$. In this case, letting $L$ be the line with infinite endpoints $\xi,\eta$, one proves that $d(p,f(p))$ is constant for $p \in L$ and that $d(q,f(q)) > d(p,f(p))$ for $p \in L$ and $q \not\in L$. Geometrically $f$ is either a "translation" along the line $L$, or what is called a "glide reflection" which is a translation along $L$ composed with a reflection across $L$.

Case 2: $Fix(f)$ consists of an entire line $L = {Fix}_{fin}(f)$ and its two infinite endpoints $\partial L = {Fix}_{inf}(f)$. In this case then $d(p,f(p))=0$ for $p \in L$ but $d(p,f(p)) \ne 0$ for $p \not\in L$. Geometrically $f$ is a reflection across $L$.

Case 3: $Fix(f)$ consists of a single finite point $p = {Fix}_{fin}(f)$. In this case $d(p,f(p))=0$ and $d(q,f(q)) > 0$ for $q \ne p$. Geometrically $f$ is a rotation around $p$ of some angle $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$.

Case 4: $Fix(f)$ consists a single infinite point $\xi = {Fix}_{inf}(f)$. Since ${Fix}_{fin}(f) = \emptyset$, $d(p,f(p))>0$ for all $p$. However, given any line $L$ with endpoint $\xi$, $\lim_{q \in L, q \to \xi} d(q,f(q)) = 0$ where we let $q$ approach $\xi$ in $\overline{\mathbb H}^2$ along the line $L$. So $d(q,f(q))$ is not constant. Geometrically $f$ is a parabolic isometry.

There's still the question of how the conclusions are proved in these four cases. But if you know the classification of isometries in more detail, i.e. if you know how the classification is related to the fractional linear transformation formulas you provided in your question, then it's not too hard to justify those conclusions.